# Array validation for table inputs in laravel 5.1

Tags: forms, validation, laravel-5.1

I am trying to give a validation for array inputs using table ,if the inputs are empty it should suppose to give a validation for each input box border as red color.
My table code is like we can add multiple no of rows by click add button like 
[My table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avq0U.png)

My validations are coming like as in the below image shown 
[My current validation output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8v4uO.png)

and i want validation something like as below using $errors and has-feedback in bootstrap laravel 
[My desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oir7P.png)

table view code:

```
<form action="{{ url('/executor/event') }}" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}" />
              <table class="table table-bordered table-striped-col nomargin" id="table-data">
                <tr align="center">
                  <td>Event Name</td>
                  <td>Event Code</td>
                  <td>Event Date</td>
                  <td>City</td>
                  <td>Country</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                    @if(null != old('eventname')) 
       @for($i=0;$i<count(old('eventname'));$i++)

          <td>
             <div class="form-group has-feedback {{ $errors->has('eventname'.$i) ? 'has-error' : '' }}" id="">
                <input type="text" class="form-control " autocomplete="off" name="eventname[]" value="{{old('eventname'.$i)}}">
                @if ($errors->has('eventname'.$i)) 
                    <p class="help-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    {{ $errors->first('eventname'.$i) }}</p>
                @endif
            </div>
         </td>
      @endfor
  @else 
      <td>
        <div class="form-group has-feedback {{ $errors->has('eventname') ? 'has-error' : '' }}" id="">
            <input type="text" class="form-control " autocomplete="off" name="eventname[]" >
        @if ($errors->has('eventname')) 
           <p class="help-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      {{ $errors->first('eventname') }}</p>
        @endif
       </div>
      </td>
 @endif

                  <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" name="eventcode[]" >
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control dob"  autocomplete="off" name="date[]" >
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" name="city[]" >
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" name="country[]" >
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="button" value="+" class="add btn btn-success">
                    <input type="button" value="-" class="delete btn btn-danger">
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              </br>
              <center> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Submit</button></center>
            </form>
```

my controller is like below:

```
public function postEvent( EventRequest $request ) {

            $data = Input::get();

            for($i = 0; $i < count($data['eventname']); $i++) {
                $c= new Event();

                $c->event = $data['eventname'][$i];
                $c->eventcode = $data['eventcode'][$i];
                $c->date = $data['date'][$i];
                $c->city = $data['city'][$i];
                $c->country  = $data['country'][$i];
                $c->save();

             }

              $request->session()->flash('alert-success', 'Event was successful added!');
              return redirect('executor/all');


}
```

and then my validation code in EventRequest.php

```
public function rules()
{



     foreach($this->request->get('eventname') as $key => $val)
                  {
                    $rules['eventname.'.$key] = 'required';
                  }


    return $rules;


}
```

I am using has-feedback error code inside my table for the first input .But still the validations are coming in the same way i could not able to find what was the mistake in my code.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Where are you calling the rules from your controller ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen : have created a validation request page named as EventRequest.php that i am including in my post function like a request `public function postUpdate(EventRequest $request){}`

Comment: Is the validation inside your model and you're calling it in __construct ?

Comment: No its inside Requests folder in laravel .

Comment: possible duplicate for the following (still not answered)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39658311/my-form-is-not-populating-when-there-is-some-validation-error-in-the-input-data